# How to redirect and keep the original url unchanged?

Tags: redirect

I have a domain name for which I created a subdomain.
This subdomain I need to be redirected to a cloud service hosted on a diferent server, but do not want to subdomain name under url to be changed. I have activated domain redirection but when I try, the url changes to the cloud server url/ip.

For instance:
- Domain: www.abcd.com
- Subdomain: cloud.abcd.com
- Cloud server: 123.456.789.0

The ideia is when the user accesses cloud.abcd.com, to be redirected to 123.456.789.0, and keep the url as cloud.abcd.com.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

A parked domain will do what you want. When you park a domain and access the parked domain in a browser, the parked domain will be displayed in the browser's address bar, but the content from the main domain will be displayed.

The following section of our documentation should be helpful:

[Parked Domains](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/ParkedDomains)

Comment: Thank you Shubham. If I understood, since I want to access the cloud server via a new subdomain, I should go to the cloud server and park the subdomain there. But there is a problem. I cannot park domains on the cloud server. The only thing I have from the cloud server is the ip address for the cloud server itself and the subdomain is created on my main domain hosting service.

Comment: After reading your docs, I believe I am wrong. Let me follow your instructions.

Comment: Shubham, it did not worked. Followed instructions on [link](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Parked+Domains#ParkedDomains-Addonvs.parkeddomains) but when tried to access the subdomain, it redirects correctly but changed the url for the cloud server IP. Perhaps it is addon domain instead of parked domain? If so I cannot use it since my domain hosting service does not allow me to configure addon domains...

Comment: Shubham, it did not worked. Followed instructions on [link](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Parked+Domains#ParkedDomains-Addonvs.parkeddomains) but when tried to access the subdomain, it redirects correctly but changed the url for the cloud server IP. Perhaps it is addon domain instead of parked domain? If so I cannot use it since my domain hosting service does not allow me to configure addon domains...

Comment: No addon domains are different , it has to be parked domains